# How to show all records in the form from the table for the same given ID

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ms-access, vba

I am working on Access forms(unbound). I have a question that I want to search records in the table by the field [ID]. When there is only one record in the table for the given [ID], form shows that record, its fine. But if there are multiple records for the given [ID], form still shows the first record and not showing the other records.
I want that form should show all records for the required [ID] in such a way that i can navigate through all records in the form view.

The SQL statement i am using is :
strSQL = "Select  * from [myTable] t where t.[ID] ='12345'
myTableRS.Open strSQL, Conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly, acCmdText

I tried for using row_count fn in access sql but its generating error.I think due to not compatibility.
I don't want to use auto generated field in the table, its a requirement.
Kindly help me how to fix it 
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: All? By definition, there should only be one item with a given id. If this isn't true, then `ID` is a misnomer.

Comment: If they are using something else a primary key for some reason you could have duplicate IDs.  Are you using a recordset?  If so, then show each record by using `.MoveNext` and a loop until .EOF

Comment: The ID is not a primary key. Yes i'm using recordset, i have tried movenext method in the for loop but the problem is that it doesn't stay on every record. I want that when user wants to go to next record then on button click it goes to next and prevoius record. The forms default view is a single form. I googled a lot for row_count function and tried on access sql but not running, if you know any compatible fn plz let me know

Comment: I have a list box that I work with in a work ticket system and it pulls a SQL statement to populate.  It is `Me.Work_Order_List.RowSource = strSQL`.  Then when a user clicks on a row it populates related fields further down the page such as department, status, downtime...

Answer (score 0):

Change the Forms Default_view property from Single to Continous
or 
enable the Next/Prev buttons on the form footer.